# Swift UIImagePickerController dynamic cast failed in getting path

Tags: ios, swift, path, uiimagepickercontroller

i'm trying to get the path of a photo from `UIImagePicker` and i'm getting "Swift dynamic cast failed" when i try to get it. Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func addPhotoButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum){

        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.SavedPhotosAlbum;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true

        self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

And here where i get the path:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
        var path: NSURL = editingInfo.valueForKeyPath("UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage") as NSURL
        println(path)
    })
}
```

The app crashes when i try to get the value of the var `path`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage` key will return an `UIImage` not the `NSURL` of that chosen image.

If you need the referece url, you need to use `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` key.

Change your following code:

```
var path: NSURL = editingInfo.valueForKeyPath("UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage") as NSURL
```

to:

```
var path: NSURL = editingInfo.valueForKey("UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL") as NSURL
```

---

> `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`
>
> Specifies the original, uncropped image selected by the user.
>
> The value for this key is a `UIImage` object.

> `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL`
>
> The Assets Library URL for the original version of the picked item.
>
> After the user edits a picked item—such as by cropping an image or
>   trimming a movie—the URL continues to point to the original version of
>   the picked item.
>
> The value for this key is an `NSURL` object.

Reference [UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Editing_Information_Keys)

Comment: Oh, thanks for the tip, i didn't pay so much attention in it, my bad, thanks!